# What to fill in "Company/Occupation" form for seminars while not being affiliated yet?

Tags: etiquette, seminars

Oftentimes it happens that you want to attend a conference/seminar while in the middle of job switch or search. In that case, you don't have an affiliation (university or company) yet.

In that case, what is acceptable to fill in the "Company/Occupation" form that is often mandatory for registering? The option of leaving it blank seems inappropriate to me. Is there any unwritten rule on what to write (future employer, past employer, blank, last academic degree)?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities. For some, "independent researcher" is appropriate. But you can also say "currently unaffiliated" instead, rather than leaving it blank. That would be fine for a short term hiatus between jobs.

Or something like "Unaffiliated, since July 2020" or whenever to emphasize that it is short term. (Short in "covid-time, anyway).

Comment: This is insightful info. Could also someone put their title (PhD, MSc, ...). In my personal case I am an abilitated engineer with MSc, don't know if "MSc Graduate in X" would be acceptable

Comment: Generally your highest degree and field should be part of any application. There are few exceptions. MSc, Engr. or something similar.